# missing an object auth when overrode the function get_app_list() from- django.contrib.admin.AdminSite

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I was trying to rearrange the order of models and apps displayed in Django admin panel.

For that I overrode the function `get__app__list()` function which is defined in Django package mentioned below.

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite

class CustomAdminSite(AdminSite):
    def get_app_list(self, request, app_label=None):
        """
        Return a sorted list of all the installed apps that have been
        registered in this site.
        """
        app_dict = self._build_app_dict(request, app_label)

        ordering_dict = {'AUTH':1,USERS': 1,'COURSE': 2,}

        # Sort the apps based on ordering_dict 
        app_list =sorted(app_dict.values(),key=lambdax:ordering_dict.get(x["name"].upper(),float('inf')))

        return app_list

admin.site = CustomAdminSite()
```

I tried this in admin.py of all my apps.

When I used the same code in inside Django library (by rewriting inside the package), it worked perfectly.

But if I inherited the AsminSite and overrode the function `get__app__list()`:
the object of auth app is not in request,
so the GROUP table is missing in admin panel,

How the object is not there when I inherit and override it?

I want to know how the object is not there when I inherit and override it.

What can I do instead?